# Maximal circles and sphere.

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $S^2$ the unit sphere given by the equation $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$. I have to prove that in every point $p \in S^2$ there is a maximum circle tangent in every direction to the plane $T_p S^2$. How can I prove it? Can I deduce from it that maximum circles are geodetics and all geodetics are maximum circle.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Suppose that $v$ is a vector in $T_p S^2$; can you tell me something about the relationship of $p$ to $v$?

Comment: What do you mean by Maximum circle? Is it great circle ?

Comment: $p$ and $v$ are ortogonal, and maximum circle is a great circle.